# How to scrape a specific <p> with no class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to web scraping.
I am going to scrape

```
<div class="p3">
<div>
<span class="poptip"><strong>BP</strong></span>
<p>110</p></div>
<div>
<span class="poptip"><strong>Weight</strong></span>
<p>55</p></div>
<div>
<span class="poptip"><strong>Age</strong></span>
<p>28</p></div>
<div>
<span class="poptip"><strong>Height</strong></span>
<p>155</p></div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to scrape is the 155.(which is the height)

I thought of getting all p.text elements into a list and take the last one out of it.
But when I try, only the 110 get as output. (Not even a list of 110, 55, 28, 155) How can I get all the p.text into a array?

This is my try:

```
p_list=[]
data =soup.find_all('div', class_='p3')
for info in data:
  p_data = para.find('p').text
  p_list.append(p_data)
  print(p_list)
```

Or, is there a way to get the text in `<p>` tag if the text in the prior span of the `<p>` tag is 'Height'?

Your help is highly appreciated as a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class_=False` as your attribute selector

If you want to get just the height, then just grab the last element:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
height = soup.find('div', class_='p3').findAll('p', class_=False)[-1]
print(height.text)

>>> 155
```

If you want to select all of the elements, then you can build a mapping using `zip`

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
div = soup.find('div', class_='p3')

tags = div.findAll('span')
nums = div.findAll('p', class_=False)

attrs = {k.text: int(v.text) for k, v, in zip(tags, nums)}
print(attrs)
>>> {'BP': 110, 'Weight': 55, 'Age': 28, 'Height': 155}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to scrape is the 155.(which is the height)

###### Option#1

To get the text of the last `<p>` in `<div>` with class "p3" you can go with `css selectors`:

```
soup.select_one('div.p3 :last-child p').text
```

###### Option#2

As alternativ you can create a list of texts of all `<p>`:

```
[x.text for x in soup.select('div.p3 p')][-1]
```

###### Option#3

> Or, is there a way to get the text in `<p>` tag if the text in the prior span of the `<p>` tag is 'Height'?

Locate the `parent` of `<strong>` that contains "Height" and its direct `<p>`:

```
soup.select_one('div:has(>:-soup-contains(Height) :not(class)) >p').text
```